# Pop up dialogs very slow on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

I don't have many speed issues regarding the new Ubuntu version (some slowdown on startup but nothing too terrible), but since I updated I've been noticing that the system pop-ups (the typical "Do you want to save this file before you quit" or "Are you sure you want to delete this file") are very unresponsive and take a long time to load. I've confirmed this behaviour in several programs - nautilus/thunar when asking to delete file, code editors when exiting with unsaved changes...

Interestingly enough when the pop-up shows once it's really responsive if called again (e.g. deleting two files in a row) but after a short while it becomes unresponsive again. Does anyone know any fix to this otherwise incredibly menial problem? Thanks

Comment: Not everyone experiences this, so it might be an issue specific to you. Provide some info on hardware and graphics card (edit your post to include it)

Comment: Sorry, I haven't really an answer to this, but I fight the same problem.
Tried a lot of things, installed other versions of nVidia drivers, then back to "nouveau".
All the same, the system is fast, but the reaction to mouse clicks very slow (about 2 seconds).
Changed the mouse too, BT or cable, no difference.
Best would be to go back to 18.04, where this problem never occurred

Comment: I don't have a good solution for this. At some point I stopped noticing it and it simply stopped happening. I don't know if something updated or anything, but it simply stopped. If someone says, e.g., @christian-benke's solution works, I'll mark it as valid/solution.

Comment: This happened to me since I upgraded to MATE 20.04 (a clean install, not an actual upgrade). Didn't happen in MATE 18.04. I only have one monitor. Still present. It's annoying.

Comment: It's really annoying. Check the PulseAudio solution below - it worked for me at least.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the problem was being caused by PulseAudio wanting to create a "close window" sound and, thus, delaying the window pop-up ([as explained here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1839136/comments/4)). Applying the following solved the issue for me:

1. If the file `~/.config/pulse/default.pa` does not exist, create it:

   ```
   touch ~/.config/pulse/default.pa
   ```
2. Modify it with the editor of your choice and add the following two lines:

   ```
   .include /etc/pulse/default.pa
   unload-module module-suspend-on-idle
   ```

I'm going to monitor the behavior in my system for a few more days before marking it as solved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the login-screen appeared very slow as well, black background with white cursor for a minute or two. I was able to fix it by linking `libusbmuxd.so.4` to  `libusbmuxd.so.6.0.0`

I checked `/var/log/syslog` and found these messages:

```
upowerd[2888]: /usr/lib/upower/upowerd: error while loading shared libraries: libusbmuxd.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

There was a link for

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusbmuxd.so -> libusbmuxd.so.6.0.0
```

but none for `libusbmuxd.so.4`

So I linked `libusbmuxd.so.4` to `libusbmuxd.so.6.0.0`:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusbmuxd.so.6.0.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusbmuxd.so.4
```

The system boots fast now and system dialogs are also snappy again.

Answer (score 0):

I also had experienced this issue, but it just stopped happening after the software update. I've checked my software update history using `less /var/log/apt/history.log`, and this is the latest log.

```
Start-Date: 2020-11-09  13:59:29
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.1603'
Upgrade: netplan.io:amd64 (0.100-0ubuntu4~20.04.2, 0.100-0ubuntu4~20.04.3), libsystemd0:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.2, 245.4-4ubuntu3.3), libsystemd-dev:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.2, 245.4-4ubuntu3.3), libasound2-data:amd64 (1.2.2-2.1ubuntu2, 1.2.2-2.1ubuntu2.1), zlib1g:amd64 (1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu1.1, 1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu1.2), zlib1g:i386 (1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu1.1, 1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu1.2), google-chrome-stable:amd64 (86.0.4240.111-1, 86.0.4240.183-1), udev:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.2, 245.4-4ubuntu3.3), alsa-utils:amd64 (1.2.2-1ubuntu1, 1.2.2-1ubuntu2), zlib1g-dev:amd64 (1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu1.1, 1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu1.2), libudev1:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.2, 245.4-4ubuntu3.3), apport:amd64 (2.20.11-0ubuntu27.10, 2.20.11-0ubuntu27.11), python3-apport:amd64 (2.20.11-0ubuntu27.10, 2.20.11-0ubuntu27.11), systemd-sysv:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.2, 245.4-4ubuntu3.3), libpam-systemd:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.2, 245.4-4ubuntu3.3), systemd:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.2, 245.4-4ubuntu3.3), libnss-systemd:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.2, 245.4-4ubuntu3.3), libasound2:amd64 (1.2.2-2.1ubuntu2, 1.2.2-2.1ubuntu2.1), libnetplan0:amd64 (0.100-0ubuntu4~20.04.2, 0.100-0ubuntu4~20.04.3), code:amd64 (1.50.1-1602600906, 1.51.0-1604600753), apport-gtk:amd64 (2.20.11-0ubuntu27.10, 2.20.11-0ubuntu27.11), python3-problem-report:amd64 (2.20.11-0ubuntu27.10, 2.20.11-0ubuntu27.11), libatopology2:amd64 (1.2.2-2.1ubuntu2, 1.2.2-2.1ubuntu2.1)
End-Date: 2020-11-09  14:00:15
```

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this problem a couple of weeks ago, after finally upgrading to 20.04 (so it wasn't because of missing software updates). None of the previously suggested solutions (e.g. pulseaudio) helped.

I checked `syslog`, and every time after initiating the slow pop-up dialog, the system was starting `upower.service` (successfully), and then there was a long delay. Disabling `upower` service didn't help, as it was still being started. So in the end I just removed the file itself:

```
cd /lib/systemd/system; sudo mv upower.service upower.service.orig
```

and it fixed the problem! Hopefully I don't need this service because it's a desktop computer, not a laptop. So far everything has been working fine.